# Java JTable SelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, listselectionlistener

I have two **JTables** filled with data on a JPanel. An user is trying to delete a row from one of the tables by selecting the row and clicking on the "delete" button. The problem for me is how to figure out  which one of the two **JTables** was focused the last ( user could click on row in table 1 then on row in table 2, then "delete" and I want to delete row from table 2 ). I would see it maybe this way:

tables have added **ListSelectionListener** that fires event **valueChanged**, when a row is selected, but now I have to somehow notify the component that contains those two tables which one was selected the last

Does anyone know how can I solve this? And please if u could deliver some example code it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a very brittle setup - what if the click didn't change the selection? Actually, the whole concept of last-to-have-been-clicked-on is hard to implement safely with whatever notification: focus might be slightly better. Anyway, you need to make it absolutely clear for the user from which of the table s/he is about to delete, f.i. by changing the text of the button or use a special highlight color in table or something ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'getSource' method of the event you're receiving to work out which table generated the event. For example,

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == jTable1.getSelectionModel()) {
      System.out.println("Event occurred in table 1");
    } else if (e.getSource() == jTable2.getSelectionModel()) {
      System.out.println("Event occurred in for table 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Register FocusListener to both tables** to track which table was focused last.

More info can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html